# Large number of failed login attempts - cPanel Hulk Brute Force

Tags: ssh, cpanel, whm, brute-force

***Mods:*** Please note that this question is specifically about a server that is managed via cPanel and WHM, which makes it different than the [alleged duplicate question](https://superuser.com/questions/21727/brute-force-password-guessing-on-ssh-server-isnt-going-to-work).

The past month, my personal web server has received thousands of these notices. Please note, my server is primarily managed by WHM/cPanel, although I have root ssh, ftp and other traditional access points.

These attacks started by attempting `root`, but have since progressed to attempting user accounts where I am not certain how they even guessed the correct usernames (albeit wrong passwords).

Is there a way to prevent these kinds of attacks from happening?

Also, here's the number of auto-bans listed just today and some smattering of IP address sources - the attack times for past month are basically around 6:30 am east coast time to 11 pm:

[image]

Comment: Do you have SSH access to the web server? Do you have root privileges?

Comment: Yes and yes... Dev ops is not my forte though, so hence why I am using WHM/cPanel

Comment: some of them are real (or variations of real - eg testuser@realdomain.com) and some of them seem random or generic (tomcat, glassfish etc)

Comment: @JakeGould   hey guys - albeit, the attack is directed at ssh, this question specifically addresses WHM / cPanel which is different than the one you linked. WHM/cPanel is a different dev-ops stack. Thus, this should not be regarded as a duplicate.

Comment: You are better off using fail2ban so it uses ipset instead of iptables only.  The iptables only is a CPU expensive way of doing things.

Comment: @ina: Have you actually tried the solutions in the marked duplicate and found that they didn't solve your problem, or you had problems trying to implement the solutions?  Did none of the solutions posted here work?  If that's the case, reopening this question is likely to just attract more answers that aren't helpful.  You would probably be better off asking a new question in which you differentiate your problem better and also describe the results of trying to apply the existing solutions.  That's your best shot at getting answers that are more applicable.

Answer (score 4):

You say this:

> The past month, my personal web server has received thousands of these
>   notices.

### Don’t panic! Just disable the `root` account on the system.

Welcome to the modern Internet! Do not take any of these notices personally and do not take any of these as a sign of a targeted attack against your web server. Rather this is a normal part of any web server existing online in some way: Armies of botnets are constantly scanning web servers for weaknesses and then *sometimes* exploit those weaknesses for various reasons/hacks.

If you are concerned, the best, simplest and easies thing you can do to remedy this situation is to disable the `root` user on the server and then assign `sudo` rights to another user on the system. By simply doing that, you kill off the issue without having to install any additional software.

Yes, some will recommend installing software like [`Fail2ban`](http://www.fail2ban.org/) on your server and while I do not think it is a bad tool in an online defense arsenal, it can give you a false sense of security if you have not done something as basic as disabling the `root` user account on the system.

The simplest way to do this on your system, is to first assign `sudo` rights to any other user on the system other than `root`. And once that is done, login as that user via SSH and run this command:

```
sudo passwd -l root
```

This will effectively lock the `root` user’s account. So let those bots attempt to login via `root` from now until forever… With `root` disabled, the efforts are futile.

### That said… Maybe you should be concerned.

But then you say this; emphasis is mine:

> These attacks started by attempting `root`, **but have since progressed
>   to attempting user accounts** where I am not certain how they even
>   guessed the correct usernames (albeit wrong passwords).

#### Don’t worry if randomly named accounts are being “hacked” even if a few usernames match users on your system.

So you say they are attempting “user accounts” but what users? Do they match valid users on the system? If they don’t match valid users on the system, then don’t worry… Even if every now and then you see an attempt to login as `tomcat` or `testuser`. These bots are just cycling through whatever dozens/hundreds/thousands of user names they have in their library to see which account they might be able to get into… And I wouldn’t lose sleep over this.

#### But if the “hack” attempts are against *purely* specific/known accounts? Then you should worry.

But that said, if somehow the attacks are targeted *only* to users that exist on your system, then you can assume the hackers somehow got a copy of your `/etc/passwd` file. First—despite it’s history name of `passwd` that file does not contain user passwords, but rather basic user information. And if the attackers have that `/etc/passwd` file, **then you have a MUCH bigger problem**.

#### If specific/known accounts are being “hacked” your web application is possibly hacked.

Typically on web servers, the main point of compromise is *not* via SSH or something like that but via the web application/server itself. Meaning if your website is based on a known CMS system like WordPress or Joomla! the hackers managed to weasel their way into your system via that web application, which then got into the system on a deeper level that is the equivalent of having SSH access but not deep SSH access.

Meaning, web servers running on software like Apache are managed by a non-root user like `www-data` or something like that. A compromise of your web application would mean a hacker has the same level of access Apache has, but not anything massively deep on a “write” level… But still a scary level of access on a “read” level.

So it is completely conceivable that a web application on your server was hacked, a payload was dropped on your server at an Apache-user level and they somehow got the `/etc/passwd` file via that compromised access. And now they are trying to gain entry via usernames in that `/etc/passwd` file.

#### What to do if your web application has been hacked.

So should you be scared? If that scenario is the case, yes. But `Fail2ban` won’t save you now. Disabling `root` can still save you to an extent. But if your web application is compromised it should be cleaned up. The SSH attempts are just hacking “gravy” on top of a server that is already infected with something.

How to go about cleaning up your web application? There is no simple answer, but if you are using WordPress—for example—consider reinstalling WordPress and then reinstalling your site customizations via backups.

And yes… Stuff like this is why backups and code recovery management is a big deal. But nobody here can explain how you should approach that at this point. It’s a whole other question entirely and based on your use of cPanel might require additional help from an outside tech. But have to mention it.

Comment: cphulk temporary bans IP addresses - is fail2ban necessary?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to stop this kind of brute force attacks by blocking suspicious attempts (based on repetitions) dropping their access to the box via `iptables`.

There's a very useful tool in this case called [Fail2Ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). This tool basically checks some log file, looking for patterns you define in the configuration fail, and if there are X attempts in Y secs from the same IP, the IP is blocked for an amount of time so it cannot try further.

As you say Dev-ops is not your forte, [there's a link](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/nginx/fail2ban/) that illustrates quite well the parts needed so it works with not much mess. So you just need to locate the log file where your brute force attempts are being logging, define a new jail, which is just the combination of the described above, and probably the most "difficult" thing is getting a pattern that would match those entries in your logfile, which are based on regexps. If you need help, you can update your question with some of these lines and I can help you synthetizing a regexp that would match.

The rest is just start the daemon and don't worry anymore about those brute-force attempts.

**Note**: There already are some built-in jails defined in Fail2Ban, which work quite well (like SSH).

Comment: I understood that the attacks were being received on the cPanel, which should be running on a web server

Comment: Ok, removed that part from my answer and made it more general